# Sharing random variables between functions

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to code a game and part of it has a combat system. I want the player to click a button as many times as they want to find an opponent, then to click the attack button when they find one they like and a timed event happens to slowly reveal the result.

The problems I'm coming against are:
- If the VAR are outside the functions, then you can only infiltrate once, but if it's inside the first function then the other ones can't use those values for the battle.
- The max_acres for victory comes across as a string so instead of 10+3=13, it becomes 103. How can I fix that?

Thank you very much for looking and I appreciate the help!

Javascript:

```
    var titles = ["Peasant", "Knight"];
    var first = ["Ada", "Adro", "Ama"];
    var last = ["nija", "har", "nake"];

    var random_name1 = titles[Math.floor(Math.random() * titles.length)] + ' ' + first[Math.floor(Math.random() * first.length)] + last[Math.floor(Math.random() * last.length)];
    var random_acres1 = (max_acres * (Math.floor(Math.random() * (140 - 75)) + 75) / 100).toFixed(0);
    var random_troops1 = (random_acres1 * (Math.floor(Math.random() * (1500 - 600)) + 600) / 100).toFixed(0);
    var random_off1 = (random_troops1 * (Math.floor(Math.random() * (1200 - 400)) + 400) / 100).toFixed(0);
    var combat_victory_acres1 = (random_acres1 * (((Math.random() * (35 - 11)) + 11) / 100)).toFixed(0);
    var combat_defeat_acres1 = (random_acres1 * (Math.floor(Math.random() * (20 - 11)) + 11) / 100).toFixed(0);
    var text_victory = 'You have been awarded with ';
    var text_defeat = 'You have lost control of ';
    var text_acres = ' acres.';

function infiltrate(){
    var x = document.getElementById("Combat_table");
    if (x.style.display === "none") {
        x.style.display = "block";
    }
    document.getElementById('combat_army_strength').innerHTML = army_strength;
    document.getElementById('combat_max_acres').innerHTML = max_acres;
    document.getElementById('random_name1').innerHTML = random_name1;
    document.getElementById('random_acres1').innerHTML = random_acres1;
    document.getElementById('random_troops1').innerHTML = random_troops1;
    document.getElementById('random_off1').innerHTML = random_off1;
};

function attack_random1(){
    document.getElementById("attack_button1").style.display="none";
    document.getElementById("infiltration").style.display="none";
            var y = document.getElementById("Combat_Results");
    if (y.style.display === "none") {
        y.style.display = "block";
    }
    setTimeout(Combat_Text4, 5000)
    var final_outcome1 = army_strength - random_off1;
    if (final_outcome1 >= 0) {
        setTimeout(Combat_Text_Victory1, 6000);
    } else {
        setTimeout(Combat_Text_Defeat1, 6000);
    }
};

function Combat_Text4() {
    document.getElementById("Combat_Results4").innerHTML = "The battle is over, a scout is dispatched to you with the results.";
}
function Combat_Text_Victory1() {
    max_acres = max_acres + combat_victory_acres1;
    var text_victory_1 = text_victory + combat_victory_acres1 + text_acres;
    document.getElementById("Combat_Results5").innerHTML = "You achieved <b>Victory!</b>";
    document.getElementById("Combat_Results6").innerHTML = text_victory_1;
    document.getElementById('max_acres').innerHTML = max_acres;
    document.getElementById('combat_max_acres').innerHTML = max_acres;
}
function Combat_Text_Defeat1() {
    max_acres = max_acres - combat_defeat_acres1;
    var text_defeat_1 = text_defeat + combat_defeat_acres1 + text_acres;
    document.getElementById("Combat_Results5").innerHTML = "You have been <b>Defeated!</b>";
    document.getElementById("Combat_Results6").innerHTML = text_defeat_1;
    document.getElementById('max_acres').innerHTML = max_acres;
    document.getElementById('combat_max_acres').innerHTML = max_acres;
}
```

HTML:

```
   <div id="Combat" class="tabcontent">

        Total Land: <span id="combat_max_acres">10</span><br>
        Total Offense: <span id="combat_army_strength">0</span><p>
        <button id="infiltration" onclick="infiltrate()">Infiltrate Kingdoms</button>
        <div id="Combat_table" style="display: none">
        <center><table>
            <tr valign="center">
                <th>Kingdom Name</th>
                <th>Acres</th>
                <th>Troop <br>Numbers</th>
                <th>Total <br>Offense</th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
            <tr id="combat_row1">
                <td><span id="random_name1"></span></td>
                <td><span id="random_acres1"></span></td>
                <td><span id="random_troops1"></span></td>
                <td><span id="random_off1"></span></td>
                <td><button onclick="attack_random1()" id="attack_button1">Attack!</button></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div id="Combat_Results" style="display: none">
        <center><table><tr>
                <td><center><span id="Combat_Results4"></span></td>
            </tr><tr>
                <td><center><span id="Combat_Results5"></span></td>
            </tr><tr>
                <td><center><span id="Combat_Results6"></span></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
```

Comment: Please try to reduce your code to a [mcve]

Comment: Wall of code - that being said, you really should create a function to clean up this duplicated code `(Math.floor(Math.random() * (20 - 11)) + 11) / 100).toFixed(0)` and you should use some named variables for these settings instead of a bunch of magic numbers. parseInt() will help you fix the 103~13 issue.

Comment: The math.round solved the max_acres problem, but I'm still running into the issue of a global variable not being generated with each button push but if they are moved into the infiltrate function then that amount can't be used for the attack_random1 function

Answer (score 0):

> The `max_acres` for victory comes across as a string so instead of 10+3=13, it becomes 103. How can I fix that?

Use [`Math.round`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/floor) instead of [`Number#toFixed`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed), because for addition numerical values, you need both operands as number, not a string.

Use `toFixed` only for displaying a number.

---

For the other parts, I suggest to use an object with arrays for same items, like

> ```
> {
>     name: [],
>     acres: [],
>     troops: [],
>     off: [],
>     victory_acres: [],
>     combat_defeat_acres: [],
>     // etc.
> }
> ```